# Monitor entire LAN traffic

Tags: networking, monitoring, network-monitor, reporting, statistics

There are home routers that are able to generate reports on how much traffic was downloaded from and uploaded to the internet, e.g. like that:
[image: traffic statistics example 1]
[image: traffic statistics example 2]

Unfortunately, my home router is not able to do something like that. I know that there are plenty of network monitoring tools out there, at least some of them should be able to imitate that functionality.

My criteria:

- The software should be able to provide reports via e-mail similiar to the one on the example
- The software should be FOSS
- The software should be able to run on a linux machine, e.g. a Raspberry Pi
- It would be nice if there were additional statistics available, e.g. what IPs on my network the traffic originated from and to what IPs on the internet it was sent
- Also it would be great if there was a long-term database for that statistics, and a webinterface, that visualizes the data.

Any recommendations? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could use [TCPDump](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump) which is an open source packet capture software, and [Splunk](https://www.splunk.com/) which can be used for the statistics parts (However, not all versions are free, and it is not open source). However, I am refraining from answering the question as I am unsure if this setup with two programs would be ideal.

Comment: @MrPublic Do you think it would be possible to use TCPDump to generate CSV files containing the originating IP-Adress, the destination IP-Adress and the size of each package?

Comment: I am not sure. I believe if you use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) and [TShark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) you can, however I do not believe it is OSS.